# Xamarin Android issue connecting via HTTPS to site with self-signed certificate: "Trust anchor for certification path not found."

Tags: android, ssl, xamarin, httpclient

I am trying to make HTTPS calls to site that has 2 SSL certificates: a self-signed certificate and a certificate that was signed by the the first certificate. When I use an HttpClient to send a request to the site, the console logs an untrusted chain, shows both certificates, then print a long stack trace of that is caused by `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found`.

I have installed both certificates on my phone and navigating Chrome to the site shows a trusted connection (it had an untrusted connection warning before I installed the certificates). I believe the issue is that the App refuses to trust self-signed certificates. I do not have access to the server and thus have no influence on its certificates, so installing a certificate signed by a trusted CA is not viable.

---

## Solutions I've tried that have not worked.

**ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback doesn't seem to run.**

I have tried using my own function for `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`, but the delegate I give it never seems to run. I have the following code in my MainActivity.OnCreate method, but the console never logs the message:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
{
  Console.WriteLine($"****************************************************************************************************");

  return true;
};
```

**HttpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback throws an exception.**

I have tried using an `HttpClientHandler` and settings its `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`, but I just get the message:

`` System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback (System.Func`5[T1,T2,T3,T4,TResult] value) ``.

Setup code:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => true;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Comment: Are you using the managed provider or the AndroidClientHandler and/or which SSL/TLS: BoringSSL or managed?

Comment: I'm just using a regular `HttpClient` with its default settings (except when I tried to use an HttpClientHandler).

Comment: I'm looking for the Android build setting for the project (Project Options / Build / Android Build / General tab), if you can still using the managed provider, use the AndroidClientHandler and clean/rebuild/retest

Comment: HttpClient implementation: Android. SSL/TLS implementation: Native TLS 1.2+. I changed the HttpClient implementation to Managed and when I tried the call got the exception `System.Net.WebException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.`.

Comment: And SSL/TLS setting?

Comment: `Native TLS 1.2+`

Comment: This worked for me on Android 5 https://stackoverflow.com/a/72280826/12100045

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was able to get this to work in both Android and iOS.

**iOS** was easy, just override `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

**For Android** I used [Bruno Caceiro's answer from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54318410/3098521) and a created Dependency Service.

In my Xamarin Forms project I added a simple interface:

```
public interface IHTTPClientHandlerCreationService
{
  HttpClientHandler GetInsecureHandler();
}
```

And in my Xamarin Android project I implemented the interface:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(HTTPClientHandlerCreationService_Android))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
  public class HTTPClientHandlerCreationService_Android : CollateralUploader.Services.IHTTPClientHandlerCreationService
  {
    public HttpClientHandler GetInsecureHandler()
    {
      return new IgnoreSSLClientHandler();
    }
  }

  internal class IgnoreSSLClientHandler : AndroidClientHandler
  {
    protected override SSLSocketFactory ConfigureCustomSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection connection)
    {
      return SSLCertificateSocketFactory.GetInsecure(1000, null);
    }

    protected override IHostnameVerifier GetSSLHostnameVerifier(HttpsURLConnection connection)
    {
      return new IgnoreSSLHostnameVerifier();
    }
  }

  internal class IgnoreSSLHostnameVerifier : Java.Lang.Object, IHostnameVerifier
  {
    public bool Verify(string hostname, ISSLSession session)
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

**Shared code** to correctly set up the HttpClient:

```
switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
{
  case Device.Android:
    this.httpClient = new HttpClient(DependencyService.Get<Services.IHTTPClientHandlerCreationService>().GetInsecureHandler());
    break;
  default:
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
    this.httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
    break;
}
```

Comment: where you write this code it got me compiler error !!

Comment: This worked for me. Excellent reply. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: It's probably in MainActivity.cs file in Android project

Comment: I get this warning: 'SSLCertificateSocketFactory.GetInsecure(int, SSLSessionCache)' is obsolete: 'deprecated'. Also for loading images this solution seems not to work. Only JSON calls are working.

Comment: I followed this solution but still get error Trust anchor for certification path not found. Do I i need to install certificate on the test device for this to work? if so, would someone show me how? Is this solution only work for self-signed certificate? how about actual certificate?