# Xamarin WebView is not showing content of specific URL (localhost that is redirecting to CAS server)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been working on Xamarin for Android and I have a problem accessing localhost from WebView. Yes, I know that on emulators and devices one can not access localhost so I installed **Conveyor by Keyoti** which gives me access to my localhost through MYIP:PORT. Localhost is setup to redirect to CAS server login that my application needs as initial login. The main problem is that webview is not showing anything but if I try to access for e.g google.com it will show main page of google. Also, I am using **Navigated** and **Navigating** properties and I always get to Navigated property which outputs *Loaded..* on the screen. Furthermore, if I try to access this "https://myip:45456" through google chrome on my device or through new incognito window it works like a charm but refuses to work inside of a webview.

Here is some xaml code that I tried because there is not much going on in the code-behind:

```
<WebView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 Navigated="WebView_Navigated" Navigating="WebView_Navigating"
                 Source = "myip:45456">
        </WebView>
```

I'm really not getting what the problem is, so if anybody has experience in this area, help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

After losing my head around this I've found out the problem lays in certificates and I'm getting this output message: *Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.*

I have tried couple of other solutions such as:
[Xamarin Android issue connecting via HTTPS to site with self-signed certificate: "Trust anchor for certification path not found."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715317/xamarin-android-issue-connecting-via-https-to-site-with-self-signed-certificate)

and workaround with `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true` in MainActivity but it's still showing the same error. 
Maybe it is something in configuration, but I can't find what it is?! :(

Comment: Are you using `https:` in the source/uri string? (i.e. what you have shown in your xaml will not work)

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm sorry, yes I am using `https:` in my xaml but i accidentally deleted it when writing the question.