# Xamarin: Loading images from ASP.NET Core backend gives certificate error - Android Amulator

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to load images from my backend into my android emulator.

I already implemented this solution: [Xamarin Android issue connecting via HTTPS to site with self-signed certificate: "Trust anchor for certification path not found."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715317/xamarin-android-issue-connecting-via-https-to-site-with-self-signed-certificate). API JSON calls are working fine, just the images are not loading.

Accessing images in the emulator chrome browser is working.
[image: Android emulator image]

My question is if anyone knows how to make loading images from local backend work?

Example code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="BoerPlaza.Views.HomePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Image HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   Aspect="AspectFit">
                <Image.Source>
                    <UriImageSource Uri="https://10.0.2.2:5001/images/1.jpg" 
                                    CacheValidity="3" 
                                    CachingEnabled="false"/>
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>

            <Label Text="Welcome to Homepage!"/>
            <Label Text="This is underlined text." FontSize="24" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Error:

```
[0:] Image Loading: Error getting stream for https://10.0.2.2:5001/images/1.jpg: Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. ---> Java.Security.Cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. ---> Java.Security.Cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0006e] in <dac4c5a4b77f4e61a5e6d9d3050dfb9f>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00014] in <dac4c5a4b77f4e61a5e6d9d3050dfb9f>:0 
  at Javax.Net.Ssl.HttpsURLConnectionInvoker.Connect () [0x0000a] in <eaa205f580954a64824b74a79fa87c62>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<>c__DisplayClass44_0.<ConnectAsync>b__0 () [0x0005a] in <eaa205f580954a64824b74a79fa87c62>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2476 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.DoProcessRequest (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, Java.Net.URL javaUrl, Java.Net.HttpURLConnection httpConnection, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+RequestRedirectionState redirectState) [0x0012e] in <eaa205f580954a64824b74a79fa87c62>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x002c7] in <eaa205f580954a64824b74a79fa87c62>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:506 
  at Xamarin.Forms.StreamWrapper.GetStreamAsync (System.Uri uri, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Net.Http.HttpClient client) [0x00038] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\StreamWrapper.cs:99 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Forms+AndroidPlatformServices.GetStreamAsync (System.Uri uri, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0003f] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Forms.cs:823 
  at Xamarin.Forms.UriImageSource.GetStreamAsyncUnchecked (System.String key, System.Uri uri, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001f7] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\UriImageSource.cs:179 
  --- End of managed Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException stack trace ---
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:231)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:196)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:153)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:674)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:551)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:507)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:426)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:354)
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:89)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:224)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:407)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:387)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:226)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    ... 24 more
[0:] Image Loading: Error getting stream for https://10.0.2.2:5001/images/1.jpg: Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. ---> Java.Security.Cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. ---> Java.Security.Cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0006e] in <dac4c5a4b77f4e61a5e6d9d3050dfb9f>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00014] in <dac4c5a4b77f4e61a5e6d9d3050dfb9f>:0 
  at Javax.Net.Ssl.HttpsURLConnectionInvoker.Connect () [0x0000a] in <eaa205f580954a64824b74a79fa87c62>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<>c__DisplayClass44_0.<ConnectAsync>b__0 () [0x0005a] in <eaa205f580954a64824b74a79fa87c62>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2476 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.DoProcessRequest (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, Java.Net.URL javaUrl, Java.Net.HttpURLConnection httpConnection, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+RequestRedirectionState redirectState) [0x0012e] in <eaa205f580954a64824b74a79fa87c62>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x002c7] in <eaa205f580954a64824b74a79fa87c62>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:506 
  at Xamarin.Forms.StreamWrapper.GetStreamAsync (System.Uri uri, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Net.Http.HttpClient client) [0x00038] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\StreamWrapper.cs:99 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Forms+AndroidPlatformServices.GetStreamAsync (System.Uri uri, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0003f] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Forms.cs:823 
  at Xamarin.Forms.UriImageSource.GetStreamAsync (System.Uri uri, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000cf] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\UriImageSource.cs:136 
  --- End of managed Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException stack trace ---
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:231)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:196)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:153)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:674)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:551)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:507)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:426)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:354)
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:89)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:224)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:407)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:387)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:226)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10665

Comment: From shared xaml code, the image url is a local IP adress (`https://10.0.2.2:5001`) , you need to keep the android device with the same segment of network with PC.